# Setting foreign key constraint name convention for all relationship types using Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

```
public class ReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention{
 public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance) {
      instance.ForeignKey(string.Format("FK_{0}_{1}",
           instance.EntityType.Name,
           instance.Name));
 }
```

}

The above code allows me to change the naming convention for foreign key relationships in the case of the type References. How can I achieve the same result for IHasManyConvention name and IHasManyToManyConvention. The change of name convention for IReferenceConvention worked perfectly displayed the way, but I'm not getting to the other types of relationships.

Answer (score 2):

For `HasMany`, I use:

```
    /// <summary>
/// Collection relationship constraint e.g. DocumentForum.Questions (1:m)
/// </summary>
public class HasManyConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Key.ForeignKey(
            string.Format(
                "[FK {1}.{0}Id references {0}.Id {2}]",
                instance.EntityType.Name,
                instance.Relationship.Class.Name,
                instance.StringIdentifierForModel));

    }
}
```

Sorry cant help you with ManyToMany - i always express these as 2 x OneToMany (to a concrete linked entity) which get covered by the above

Comment: I've been debating whether that is a good best practice.  Because if you don't start with a Concrete, and then you decide to add a surrogatekey (or any scalar-attribute) to the relationship, aka, the link-table in the DDL, you have to rework a lot of stuff...to after-the-fact inject the Concrete.  Good to know somebody has seen this.